# Does there exist curve (for example, in $\mathbb R^2$) that either touches itself or intersects itself at every one of its points?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, curves

I really do not even know how to constructively think about this question that I wanted to post before, but delayed. I know that there are space-filling curves and curves of positive area and those that do not have tangent anywhere but the example of curve that either touches itself or intersects itself at every one of its points i did not see.

I do not know what I would even conjecture about this problem, that it does exist or does not, I really do not know. When I try to visualize construction of such an example it starts to look as some compact set with positive area.

Please, I am an amateur, so would like that your exposition is as elementary as possible, if possible.

I also want no cheating, for example the cheating would be $f(t)=(\cos(t),\sin(t))$ for $t \in [0,4 \pi$]. Then someone could interpret that this circle touches itself at every one of its points since it goes twice through every point.

You know that we seek for examples which are marvellous and not trivial (if possible), if there are any.

Comment: Maybe the condition you're thinking of is lack of mutually covering portions of the curve, something along these lines: a curve $\gamma$ is "non-cheating" if for no distinct non-trivial segments $[l_1, r_1]$ and $[l_2, r_2]$ there are monotonous continuous functions $f: [0, 1] \to [l_1, r_1]$ and $g: [0, 1] \to [l_2, r_2]$ such that we have $\gamma(f(t)) = \gamma(g(t))$ for all $t \in [0, 1]$.

Comment: Maybe [this Julia set](https://imgur.com/a/yeuBq) (shown here is the quadratic filled Julia set with parameter $-1$; I refer to its boundary, of course), which can be continuously (but not injectively) parametrized by external angles (I think!), is the sort of thing you want. But it only has a countable dense set of "double points", I somehow doubt you can do better.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen i also have some ideas on how to build curves that have countably many double points in every neigbourhood of every point, although I am facing serious difficulties with orientation (where to go on a curve after big enough number of steps) and terms "right" and "left" but when i just think of construction of double-pointedness at every point my whole knowledge of  analysis and topology seems insufficient and does not apply here.

Comment: @MikhailTikhomirov Yes, it is just the requirement that the curve does not go over itself when she hits the point of itself.

Comment: Take a Peano square filling curve and complement it by another Peano curve from the ending point. Of course, this is a totally idiotic example but it formally satisfies all the requirements stated so far.

Comment: @fedja What does exactly mean "complement it by another Peano curve from the ending point."?

Comment: @AntoinedePaladin Once you have finished drawing the first one, start drawing the second one from the point you ended at (like when you draw a broken line, you draw a sequence of intervals each next one beginning when the previous one ended). The resulting curve covers the square twice and you can easily ensure that it doesn't go over itself on any interval.

Comment: @fedja I cannot imagine curves that are like the ones in question that do not fill-space. I believe that every one of them must fill the space.

Comment: @AntoinedePaladin Fill something like Serpinski's triangle instead. But yes, they cannot look like what one normally would call a curve.